# Kullback divergence vs chi-square divergence

Tags: probability-theory

If the probability measures $P$ and $Q$ are mutually absolutely continuous, Kullback divergence $K(P,Q)=\int \log\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}Q}\right)\mathrm{d}P$, and chi-square divergence $ \chi^2(Q,P) = \int \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}P}−1\right)^2 \mathrm{d}P$, how to prove that

$$ K(P,Q) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\chi^2(Q,P)$$

Comment: What did you try? Which similar problems can you solve?

Comment: If you remove the 1/2 factor, then the inequality holds (assuming log means natural log).

Comment: jvc since you haven't commented I think I can't use @jvc but since you put a bounty I would like to ask you if you know anything more about this identity? if it appears as an exercise somewhere I suppose we can assume is true and just try to prove it but if not we should try also to see if it false, do you have some motivation behind this identity?

Comment: This inequality comes from "introduction to non parametric estimation" by Tsybakov. I spent a lot of time on it (nice training ahah), and I am sure that it is terribly false( consider binomials laws). I put a bounty on this inequality too early...

Comment: @jvc what I suggested about assuming it was true in case it was an exercise in a book to narrow the problem was totally wrong, I looked the book up and someone has written the solutions to the problems, another counterexample is given [there](https://pavelchigansky.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/pavelchigansky/files/tsybakovsolutions.pdf#page=21)

Comment: Thanks! It may be useful to know what is the right version of this exercice.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to saying that $P$ and $Q$ are mutually absolutely continuous, you also need to require that expectations, defining Kullback divergence and $\chi^2$ divergence exist.

The inequality as stated does not hold. Indeed, consider $P$ a measure corresponding to $\operatorname{Beta}(2,1)$ random variable, and $Q$ to uniform random variable, i.e.
$$
  \mathrm{d}P = 2 x \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x) \mathrm{d} x \qquad
   \mathrm{d}Q = \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
Then, it is easy to compute that
$$
   K(P,Q) = \int_0^1 \log(2x) \cdot 2 x \mathrm{d} x = \log(2) - \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.19131472\ldots
$$
whereas
$$
   \chi^2(Q,P) = \int_0^1 \left( 2x-1 \right)^2 \cdot 2 x \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{3}
$$
Clearly $K(P,Q) > \frac{1}{2} \chi^2(Q,P)$.

**N.B.** If $\operatorname{Beta}(2,2)$ is used for $Q$ and $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ for $P$, then the integral defining $\chi^2(Q,P)$ is easily seen to diverge.

Comment: Sorry, Sasha, I write wrong formula, it should be χ2(Q,P)=∫(dQ/dP−1)2dP